# How can I use company's ignore-case with pip-requirements.el

Tags: company-mode, pip-requirements

I am looking for a way to ignore case when discovering packages through company's completion with [pip-requirements.el](https://github.com/Wilfred/pip-requirements.el/blob/master/pip-requirements.el) only.

---

#### Edit:

Using `completion-ignore-case`, "breaks" the highlight of candidates:

[image]

Comment: What if you `(setq completion-ignore-case t)`?

Comment: I've tried but: 1) It sets this behavior for all company completions accross all modes. 2) It messes up the highlight of the candidates match.

Comment: Can't you set `completion-ignore-case` buffer locally in a corresponding mode hook?

Comment: i assumed it would still mess with the highlight of candidates, and so I was looking for another method. It breaks the candidate highlighting.

Comment: Breaks the highlighting how?

Comment: @Dmitry Edited and added screencast.

Comment: @MathieuMarques Thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `completion-ignore-case` is the way to go.

The input match highlighting should be fixed in [9b895568](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/commit/9b89556880e326ec3391cfda2a87eada101eaaae).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. :) Out of curiosity, how much time should we wait before  code propagates to Melpa, roughly?

Comment: Looks like it took 1 hour.

Comment: I've tried `setq-local` in a `:config` directive from `use-package`. It doesn't seem to be doing what I need. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to `setq-local` in a function that's added to the hook of the corresponding major mode.

Comment: Which would be `pip-requirements-mode-hook` in this case.

Comment: Yes. Got all mixed up in my head. Setting a local at initialization won't do much... Thanks again, great package ;)